# Command to send SMS from terminal Using Kannel + SMPP

Tags: command-line, sms

I have Installed the kannel on my server, configured the kannel file as per the requirement. Started the Bearerbox and SMSBox, both boxes are running fine.

**Now I want to check if the SMS is being pushed or not?**

Any one having knowledge kannel + SMPP then please try to help me. If you cant then please give me relevant website, where I can ask the same question.

Thanks Regards,
Rohit Bind

Answer (score 2):

you can call kannel direct in the command line with a wget (or curl) like:

```
curl "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?user=xxxxxx&pass=yyyyy&to=56976808016&text=test_TLV&meta-data=%3Fsmpp%3FMAS_APP_ID%3D6%26MAS_SVC_ID%3D189%26MAS_CONT_ID%3D1%26MAS_CONT_DESC%3DTrivia&dlr-mask=31"
```